# HtmlToOpenXml htmlconverter not parsing image tag in c#

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

On converting html to docx using htmlconverter openxml, image is not being parsed in docx file.I am attaching my code reference below

```
public void ExportToWord()
    {
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=test.docx";
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            WordDocument doc = new WordDocument(mem);
            MariGold.OpenXHTML.HtmlParser _HtmlParser = new MariGold.OpenXHTML.HtmlParser("<img src=\"data: image/png;base64, iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\" alt=\"Red dot\" />");
            doc.Process(_HtmlParser);
            doc.Save();
            Response.BinaryWrite(mem.ToArray());
        }
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: A quick glance at the source code tells me it probably doesn't support data urls.